# Удаление элемента очереди Dataflow

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

Необходимо удалять группу поставленных в очередь dataflow задач. Проще говоря нужно по необходимости удалять какой то элемент очереди dataflow. Реализовал пока с помощью запуска тела блока через таск и отменяю его так сказать локальным токеном. Все вроде и работает, но может произойти ситуация, когда задачи одной группы будут находиться хаотично разбросанные по "очереди" и если отменять их через таск, то dataflow блоку нужно будет сначала пройти все нужные блоки что бы сработала отмена.
А так как в очереди могут быть и другие задачи, то на это потребуется много времени.

То есть вопрос в следующем: есть ли какие то нативные способы удалять элементы коллекции dataflow или более правильные реализации?

Comment: Вы используете `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions.CancellationToken`?

Comment: @andreycha Да, но как я понимаю оно работает для всего блока, а не для отдельных элементов.

Comment: Непосредственно функциональность изъятия задач с конвейера отсутствует. А чем они вам мешают? Пусть повисят немного, а когда до них дойдет очередь, вы проверите токен отмены и завершите задачу.